# Jquery call predefined functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

All of the tutorials I see online are defining functions on the fly to respond to event handlers.  I am trying to call a JS function when my form is submitted, but it never works quite right.  In PHP:

```
echo "$(document).ready(function() { $(\"#newDate\").submit( ValidateForm('".$ID."') ); });";
```

When the user hits enter for the input field, instead of submitting my form I need it to call a javascript function.  This line of code repeatedly calls my function in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need an anonymous function to wrap it, like this:

```
echo "$(document).ready(function() { $('#newDate').submit(function() { ValidateForm('".$ID."'); }); });";
```

I changed to single quotes on `#newDate` as well just because it's a bit cleaner *to me*, if it doesn't work for you just leave the `\"` style...it's not related to the actual problem.

Without the anonymous function it's trying to validate the field *immediately* and assign the *result* to the event handler, which isn't what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Close.  It should look like this:

```
echo "$(function() {\n\t",
     "$('#newDate').submit(function() {\n\t\t",
     "ValidateForm('" . $ID . "');\n\t",
     "});\n});";
```

I added some formatting to make things look more readable once you examine source.

Notice the new anonymous function.  That will get things working right for you.